# Convert Dataset to javascript Obj

Tags: javascript

I have a dataset that I need to convert to a Javascript object, as below. How can this be done?

```
//Jscript
var dataobj = [["Jan",12],["Feb",24],["Mar",66]]
```

Is the only way to look through the record on the server side, construct the data, and send it back to client side?

Comment: What do you mean "convert to javascript object"?  What do you want the final data to look like?  Please show JS object definition that matches what you want.

Comment: Probably easier to convert to JSON on the server side.

Comment: I replaced the jQuery tag with the JavaScript tag as I don't really know why jQuery would be relevant here.

Comment: Do you mean ADO.NET Dataset in an ASP.NET code?

Comment: You haven't provided us with nearly enough information to answer your question. What is the server side language? What type of data are you converting? Have you looked into JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your data with a loop. Then put in in the way you want like this:

Html:

```
<div id="out"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var dataobj = [["Jan",12],["Feb",24],["Mar",66]];

var dataOut = "";

for(i = 0; i < dataobj.length; i++){
    console.log(dataobj[i].length);
    for(i2 = 0; i2 < dataobj[i].length; i2++) {
        dataOut = dataOut + " " + dataobj[i][i2];        
    } 
    dataOut = dataOut + "<br>";
}

$('#out').html(dataOut);
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zoutepopcorn/zKVN4/)

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that you want it key/valued. Just guessing.

```
var dataobj = [["Jan",12],["Feb",24],["Mar",66]];
var dataObjHash = {};
for(var i = 0; i < dataobj.length; i++){
   dataObjHash[ dataobj[i][0] ] = dataobj[i][1];
}
dataObjHash; // <-- this returns: Object { Jan=12, Feb=24, Mar=66 }
```